# Writing Logs in Google Addons

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a Google Spreadsheet add-on that will pull data from web pages (calling URLFetch with an hourly trigger) and write the data to a spreadsheet.

However, I only want this add-on to only write to the same spreadsheet even if the user is opening the add-on in a different sheet.

Is it possible to force the user to work with that add-on only in a particular sheet? TIA.

Comment: Clarity is needed, please update your question with this info... You've used 'sheet' and 'spreadsheet' interchangeably in the second paragraph - which do you mean? When you say "force the user to work with...", do you mean that you want the particular sheet to be made active (i.e. popped to the top for the user)? Or do you want the add-on to be disabled when other sheets are active? And what does any of this have to do with "Writing Logs"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, when calling the SpreadsheetApp service you can call the sheet you want by [name](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)) or the one you need from the list of [sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets).

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetName()
```

Then you would write the information in that sheet.
hope it helps.